# How do you recall a specific object when using a variable to instantiate?

Tags: python, oop, object, instance

All the code I have seen to create an instance of an object has used a variable and the use of the instance of an object is short lived, like a game. A new game replaces that instance and there is no need to recall previous objects. Or I have seen manually produced instances not using a catchall variable. Like `c1` and `c2` so on and so forth.

```
class Child:
    def __init__ (self, name,):
        self.name = name


child = Child(name)
```

I have created multiple instances of my object and have attached them inside another class by appending them to a list. However if I were to change an attribute of an instance, I don't know how to call it with a generic variable 'child' used to instantiate.  I can do this when I have used `c1`  or `c2` to instantiate : like `c1.name`. But I would have to manually write `c1` or `c2`. Versus when I call `child.name` I only return the last child that was created.

Does anyone have an a suggestion?

Comment: please edit your code to be in a code block so it is readable

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, you can use a list to store the instances of the object you create. For example, building on the code you have, you could do something like:

```
my_objects = []

for name in ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'):
    child = Child(name)
    my_objects.append(child)
```

Then, if you wanted to recall the second object you created, you could acess it from the list:

```
child = my_objects[1] # this is the second one you created
print(child.name) # this prints 'two'
child.name = 'second' # now the name is second!
```

Alternatively you could directly call `my_objects[1].name = 'second'`.

Comment: Just a note, you can also do this using a list comprehension: `my_objects = [Child(name) for name in ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')]`

Comment: I'm aware that this could be written more concisely, but I feel that given the question, it was more important to explain clearly and simply without introducing more 'advanced' language features :)

Comment: No worries, just thought I'd slide that in there